# Using Galois theory, determine the number of subfields of an extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let K be a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 12 such that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{12}$. I want to determine the number of subfields of $K$ of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ for each $1\leq n \leq 12$.

I am just learn Galois theory so I do not know if I understand correctly, but this is what I have: The subgroups of $Z_{12}$ are $<1>,<2>,<3>,<4>,<6>,<12>=<0>$, so that there are exactly 4 intermediate fields between $K$ and $F$ (is that correct?). So $<2>$ corresponds to a unique subfield of dimension $2$ over $F$, $<3>$ corresponds to a unique subfield of dimension $3$ over $F$, etc.

Is the above correct? I am sorry if this is a bad question. I am new to this and hope to not bother anyone. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The dimension of an intermediate field $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be *index* of the corresponding subgroup in the Galois group $G$. [EDIT: error on my part, deleted the text :) ] (unrelated comment: use \langle and \rangle for prettier angle brackets when writing out a generating set in tex)

Comment: @ebrahim - the OP is correct! <2> has $6$ elements in it, and index  $2$ in $\mathbb Z/12$.

Comment: Yup just realized that, thanks! I messed up.

Comment: You have the correspondence as it should be, although I think usually it is a good idea to include $K$ and $F$ - or equivalently $(1)$ and $G$, to get $6$ intermediate fields/groups ... For a few other examples, you might take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory; if you search for 'examples of galois correspondence', you will find many, many more: e.g.., http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorrexamples.pdf

Comment: In fact - you asked for $1\le n \le 12$, so you 'must' include the two 'end points'.